# toast notification via CSS3 animation

Tags: css

Today is officially my first visit to css3 animations and to be honest i cannot get it to work in FF. I have a simple notification system in place that calculates the number of sent messages to a user and It displays the value in a small red circle that blinks.

My problem is that it does not blink and also I'm having sizing, padding issues using radius.

Any help on this would be fantastic.

```
.alert-notification 
{
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    width: 21px !important;
    height: 21px !important; 
    padding-left: 6px !important;
    padding-right: 6px !important;
    padding-bottom: 1px !important;
    background-color:#f35958 !important;
    text-align:center !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:-5px;

    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { /*opacity: 1.0;*/ background-color:#f35958;}
    50% { /*opacity: 0.0;*/ background-color:#CD0000;}
    100% { /*opacity: 0.7;*/ background-color:#8B0000; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { /*opacity: 1.0;*/ background-color:#f35958;}
    50% { /*opacity: 0.0;*/ background-color:#CD0000;}
    100% { /*opacity: 0.7;*/ background-color:#8B0000; }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
    0% { /*opacity: 1.0;*/ background-color:#f35958;}
    50% { /*opacity: 0.0;*/ background-color:#CD0000;}
    100% { /*opacity: 0.7;*/ background-color:#8B0000; }

}
```

This works great in Chrome! Not tested in IE. Even if this does not blink, i would very much like the value to be aligned within centre of the circle.

Regards,

Terry

Comment: could you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see the issue?

Comment: @Banana fiddle as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/f3sh894w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because FireFox prioritizes `!important` over keyframes, unlike chrome.

you have set

```
.alert-notification 
{
    background-color:#f35958 !important;
}
```

which prevents the keyframes from animating the background color. remove the `!important` and it will work.

<kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/f3sh894w/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Fantastic work! I will certainly remember that one. Do you have any suggestions on how to keep the value central in modern browser?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what value, and central relatively to which element?

Comment: Sorry please ignore that last question. I've spent countless hours an a fairly complicated project and I'm starting to get a little confused :)

Comment: no problem :) by the way, its very easy to center an element horizontally, either set its width to a limitted number and apply `text-align:center;` to its parent, or apply `margin:0 auto;` to the lement itself. to center it vertically, you need to set the `line-height` of the parent same as the `height` of the parent, and set `vertical-align:middle;` to the parent and a limitted height to the centered element.